# What are the practical differences between German Lutheran and Swiss Reformed traditions?

Tags: protestantism, reformed-theology, lutheranism, germany

I know very little about the German Lutheran church and what set them appart from the religion I've been raised in, Swiss Reformed. However, my understanding is that they are closer to Catholics, and they are sort of hybrid catholic-reformed. For example, they decorate their churches while we reformed don't.

I'm more interested in the differences in practice, as what are the religious traditions, rather than the theoretical aspect of what Luther and Calvin respectively thought was right.

I ask this because religion is often taught from one's mother, and my great-great-great-grandmother immigrated from Germany and was a German Lutheran; does it makes me a subconscious German Lutheran? How easy would it have been for her to convert from German Lutheran faith to Swiss Reformed faith?